# I'm stuck in the endless celebration of my newfound punching powers

Tags: rayman-forever

> [image: screenshot]
>
> *Rayman is not impressed with my cutscene quitting skills.*

I've reached the very first cutscene in the game and I can't find the way out. Walking to either side does nothing. Pressing ESC brings the game menu, but little else. I can only throw my fists for however long I want to and listen to Rayman's impatient calls for action.

What am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to punch one of those purple fruits at the top, which makes them fall. They're bouncy and allow me to jump higher. The road continues on the otherwise out-of-reach cliff.

[image]

Comment: Fist the fruit. I see.

Comment: I will never see Rayman the same way.